# Why is that JQuery live() works while delegate() not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

The code I'm dealing with is too complicated so I can't paste my codes here.

But the situation I met is taht: 
A .js file being included in two different htmls,
In one html the `delegate()` worked but in the other just no effect.
Then I replace `delegate()` with `live()`, and then in both html it worked fine.

I'm just curious why this happend..
May it because I included too many different js files in the two htmls and may be causing some conflict?

Comment: could you give us some code of both examples?

Comment: Are you reloading the selector you set delegate() on via AJAX in the other page as this could be the reason it doesn't work

Comment: This is a bit too theoretical question. It would be really helpful if you provide minimal version of the js and html files, so we can have a look.

Comment: Thought I wish to paste some code here but the codes are too complex, html and js files are both more than 500 lines with many dynamically generated part, it's too hard to be  abstracted simple enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to rember that when you delegate() to some element that element must be present in the dom when you call delegate.

So if you call

```
 $('#mycontainer').delegate(....
```

the element with id mycontainer must be present otherwise delegate() won't work. One workaround that cause some overhead is delegating to the `document` or to the `body`:

```
 $('body').delegate()
```

Live() always works because in reality you are delegating to the body.

Comment: Thanks! I think the first point may be the reason. I thought that delegate() is just one more efficient replacement of live(). I didn't notice that delegate() need the element already be set.